# Download function for .pdf and .jpg or .jpeg files

Tags: php, file, pdf, download, jpeg

I have wrote some code with JavaScript and PHP on the server-side. This code helps me to download files from the storage, apart from .pdf and .jpeg files. In the case, I try to download .pdf or .jpg, .jpeg files, it is just always loads and after few seconds shows the content of files on the same page.

```
 $downloadFile = 'openFiles/'.$path;
    file_put_contents($downloadFile, $decrypted_code);
$file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $path)));
```

*...finding proper file*

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($downloadFile)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($downloadFile));
flush();
```

*...Realizing download function*

```
  $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif','docx', 'pdf', 'txt', 'png','xlsx'];
```

*...The list of files which program can download, except .pdf .jpeg .jpg*

If download .pdf file it writes

> waiting for cash

and I see the page on the picture below [image: pdf download]

the same is for the jpeg

[image: jpeg download]

Comment: `It is just always loads and shows the content of files on the same page.` , can u tell what do u want , what is requirement

Comment: @aryanknp  means that for all other extensions download function works, but for these files not

Comment: can u try this `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` instead  of `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");`

Comment: octet-stream will produce a ugly icon in save select, use the correct mime type for the file

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Can you explain please, where to use the correct type? before "realizing download function"? How to do this?

Comment: This is my code `header("Pragma: public");header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".basename($downloadFile)."\";" );header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");header("Content-Length: ".filesize($downloadFile));`

Comment: @aryanknp @LawrenceCherone I have tried `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); ` Yes it works now for the same file in different ways :) BUT for pdf it still the SAME.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have tried to write `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');` and it doesn't help. The page gives me the same output

Comment: Use the network tab in your browser’s developer tools. Make sure the content-disposition header is actually being set.

Comment: It shows `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`  in network tab headers, after loading .pdf file

Comment: @Quentin I can not find content-disposition on network tab

Comment: Then something is going wrong with your attempt to set the headers. Either the PHP is broken in some way (and you should create a [mcve]) or your server has some configuration that is changing / stripping the headers (which you can test by using a different server, such as the [built in PHP server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).